# Why is JQuery DataTables not showing my data from IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, indexeddb

I am trying to have data extracted from my indexed database displayed on a jQuery datatable. I am storing the data (JSON) in an array. It is of the form `[{key:'---', type:'---', source:'---', destination:'---',value:'---'},...]`. I can `console.log()` it and see that the data is, in fact, there, but the datatable does not seems to be accepting it. I see the message 'No data available in the table'.

```js
function initDB(){
  let request = window.indexedDB.open('bankDB', 1);
  request.onerror = function(event){
    console.log('Error loading the database ' + request. error.message);
  };

  request.onsuccess = function(event){
    console.log("The database was successfully loaded.");
    myDB = event.target.result;
    printTable();
    initDataTable();
    myDB.onerror = function(event){
      console.log('error: ' + event.target.error.message);
    };
  };

  request.onupgradeneeded = function(event){
    console.log('Upgrading the database.');
    myDB = this.result;
    myDB.onerror = function(event){
      console.log('error: ' + event.target.error.message);
    };
    const table = myDB.createObjectStore('bankTable',{keyPath: 'key', autoIncrement: true});
  };
}

function initDataTable(){
  const table = myDB.transaction(['bankTable'], 'readonly').objectStore('bankTable');
  table.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    const cursor = event.target.result;
    if(cursor){
      DT.push(cursor.value);
      cursor.continue();
    }

  };

  let theTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    data: DT,
    'columns':
    [
      {data: 'key'},
      {data: 'type'},
      {data: 'source'},
      {data: 'destination'},
      {data: 'value'}
    ]
  });

  theTable.draw();
}
```

Comment: I think you may want to [edit] your question, to try to clean up the code formatting. It is fragmented and not easy to follow. Are the different fragments presented in the order in which they actually appear in your web page? Is there a `$(document).ready()` function? I would guess (and it is only a guess) that your code is initializing the DataTable _before_ the `DT` variable has been populated (in `'data': DT,`). Hence: no data.

Comment: Also, welcome! - and if you have not done so already you can take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Where is the variable `DT` initialized?

Comment: It is declared just above it. I am fairly certain after a bit of investigation, that it is a timing issue. I am not sure though how to delay the creation of my datatable until DT variable is loaded completely